# what is the php.ini file format means

Tags: php

I'm New to  php. I found file format of "example.ini". So what is this? what is php.ini file?
Following contains a sample file

```
<?php 
$x = 75;
$y = 25;     
function addition() {
    $GLOBALS['z'] = $GLOBALS['x'] + $GLOBALS['y'];
}    
addition();
echo $z;
?>
```

Comment: no idea what your asking

Comment: what exactly does this code you posted have to do with `example.ini` ?

Comment: Is your question about reading/writing `.ini` files in PHP, about the `php.ini`-file or about the totally unrelated snippet you posted? This question is very very unclear...

Comment: @MasterPiece http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php

Answer (score 1):

PHP.ini is very useful and it is a configuration file that is used to customize behavior of PHP at runtime. This enables easy administration in the way you administer Apache web server using configuration files. The Settings in which  upload directory, register global variables, display errors, log errors, max uploading size setting, maximum time to execute a script and other configurations is written in this file.

Answer (score 1):

The `php.ini` file is where you declare changes to your PHP settings. You can use the default settings for the server, change specific settings by editing the existing `php.ini`, or create a new text file and name it `php.ini`.

**Default Settings**

The server is already configured with standard settings for PHP which your site will use by default. Unless you need to change one or more of the settings, there is no need to create or modify a `php.ini` file.

**Create a php.ini File**

This file should be created in your cPanel Home directory `(/home/username/)`. For VPS Plesk users the file should already exist in the following directory:

```
/var/www/vhost/$DOMAIN/etc/php.ini
```

Be sure to replace `username` with your actual cPanel user name, and `$DOMAIN` with your actual domain.

You can follow this [The configuration file in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php)